# TableModel vs ColumnModel: who owns the column value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

What's the difference between `JTable.getModel().getColumnName()` and `JTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).getHeaderValue()`? The two don't seem to share any data. My guess is that `TableModel.getColumnName()` indicates the textual representation of a column while `TableColumn.getHeaderValue()` and `TableColumn.getHeaderRenderer()` determine what the column looks like (it doesn't need to be plain text).

What guarantees that the two are kept in sync? What happens if the two conflict?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If a [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) is constructed with a [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) but without a [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) will create a [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) using [createDefaultColumnModel()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#createDefaultColumnModel%28%29) and set [autoCreateColumnsFromModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getAutoCreateColumnsFromModel%28%29) to true. When this property is true, the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) will populate the [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) with values from the [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).

No one seems to guarantee that the two are kept in sync. Case in point, [JTable.getColumnName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnName%28int%29) will return the [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) column name regardless of what the [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) actually displays on the screen.

Another interesting thing I noticed is that [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) is limited to String columns whereas [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) allows you to pass any Object to the [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#getHeaderRenderer%28%29). The Javadoc [says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setHeaderValue%28java.lang.Object%29) that the values are restricted to Strings but in fact this is implementation-specific. Nothing prevents you from writing an implementation that uses a [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) value.

**In summary**: [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) is the ultimate owner of column values. [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html)  only asks [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) for values only if it doesn't already have one. For example, in the case where you pass a column into [JTable.addColumn()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#addColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) without specifying a header value.

Comment: And you can resync them with `JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel()` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#createDefaultColumnsFromModel()